# problema al ejecutar comando python3.11 manage.py runserver en python 3.11

Tags: python

tengo un problema al ejecutar el comando python3.11 manage.py runserver pues me genera el siguiente error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3' alguien me puede ayudar soy nueva en python y django. estoy usando esta version ya que la base de datos que voy a utilizar es la de firebase y con la version 3.8 de python la conexion a esta base de datos me dio problemas.

Answer (score 0):

El módulo sqlite3 no está instalado en tu entorno de Python. Si bien el módulo es parte de la biblioteca estándar de Python, no está habilitado de forma predeterminada. Para corregir el error, tenes instalar el módulo sqlite3.

podes hacerlo con este comando:

```
pip3 install sqlite3
```

o

```
python3 -m pip install sqlite3
```

Una vez que lo tengas instalado, deberías poder ejecutar el script manage.py sin ningún problema.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta nicP pero cuando ejecuto lo que me dices me salen estos errores, ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sqlite3 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sqlite3